# How to put object in realm using map on rxJava?

Tags: android, realm, retrofit, rx-java

I need to save the result of a JSON in my realm offline database.I've downloaded it using RxJava.
So I need to use this code:

```
public Subscription loadObjectsFromNetwork() {
return objectApi.getObjects()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe(response -> {
        try(Realm realmInstance = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
            realmInstance.executeTransaction(airport -> realm.insertOrUpdate(airport.objects));
        }
    });
  }
```

my problem is that i'm at the beginning of RxJava and I don't understand how to put it in my code.

This is what I've made:

```
  Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .baseUrl(GithubService.SERVICE_ENDPOINT).build();

            GithubService service = retrofit.create(GithubService.class);

            service.getAirport()
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<Airport>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted()
                        {
                         bClear.setText("OK");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNext(List<Airport> airports)
                        {

                        }
                    });

        }
    });
```

and it works well (it downloads all), but where could I put the call to load objects into my offline database?
Thanks

Comment: In place of `bClear.setText("OK");`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce is there a way to not download all data in a List, but put it directly when it is downloaded?

Comment: Depends on your API

Comment: @EpicPandaForce API of Android?

Comment: No, your REST API